# rendered - Exception getting value of property

Tags: jsf

What does this error mean?

> javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: /WEB-INF/view/template.xhtml
>   @18,58 rendered="#{seguridadACG.esRol eq 'Productor'}": Exception
>   getting value of property esRol of base of type :
>   org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_374   at
>   com.sun.facelets.el.LegacyValueBinding.getValue(LegacyValueBinding.java:60)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:1075)
>     at
>   com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.encodeRecursive(ComponentSupport.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.encodeRecursive(ComponentSupport.java:239)
>     at
>   com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:580)
>     at
>   org.ajax4jsf.framework.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:108)
>     at
>   org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:384)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:138)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
>     at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
>     at
>   org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.xmlfilter.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:127)
>     at
>   org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.xmlfilter.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

My class is:

```
@Stateful
@Name("seguridadACG")
public class SeguridadControllerBean implements SeguridadController, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7838664976264342564L;          

    private String esRol;

    public String getEsRol(){
        this.esRol = "Productor";
        return this.esRol;
    }

}
```

Inside XHTML, i'm put this code:

```
<h:outputText   value=" Productores" rendered="#{seguridadACG.esRol == 'Productor'}" />
```

Somebody... please! help!
Thanks

Comment: It means your `seguridadACG` object in request/session/application attribute doesn't have an `esRol` field declared with its respective get following JavaBean conventions. By the presented code, looks like it should work. Since looks like you're using CDI, try decorating your bean as `@Named("seguridadACG") @RequestScoped` instead of the other annotations and try again.

Comment: `@Stateful` is a EJB annotation and you trying to use that bean in `JSF EL`. So, try `@SessionScoped` instead

Comment: @SRy if the bean has the `@Named` annotation from CDI, then the bean can be used in Facelets page with no problems. Of course, I won't advice having an EJB as a view bean to begin with.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza...I agree with you as it creates a instance of the bean. But does that bean instance handles in the same way as `@sessionscoped` or `@RequestScoped` in the facelets?

Comment: @SRy if no scope is provided, then it will use default scope which is `@RequestScoped`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - isn't `@NoneScoped` the default?

Comment: @kolossus refer to [`@ManagedBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) javadoc: *The scope of the managed bean is declared using one of `NoneScoped`, `RequestScoped`, `ViewScoped`, `SessionScoped`, `ApplicationScoped`, or `CustomScoped` annotations. **If the scope annotations are omitted, the bean must be handled as if the `RequestScoped` annotation is present.***

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - For some reason, I always thought it was the other way. Now I know, thanks